# Why weren't IG-series droids used for war?

Tags: star-wars

The IG-11 droid on the Mandalorian was designed to be an incredibly efficient warrior able to take on the most dangerous of bounties. It has overwhelming damage output because its swiveling lenses and body allow it to independently aim two blasters to rapidly unleash a torrent of accurate gunfire across a 360 degree arc. In the below GIF we see it taking on a small army of mercenaries attacking from all directions.

[image]

In addition, its Durasteel frame was highly resistant to blaster fire and it was able to survive multiple shots from a heavy cannon (pictured below) with seemingly negligible damage.

[image]

All in all, the IG droid would drastically outclass all but the most talented or Force-sensitive organics, and are more than a match for stormtroopers or the Trade Federation's B1 battle droid. Why were IGs never used for war?

Comment: Expensive and prone to deciding to murder its owners?

Comment: Thanks Valorum, does make sense if that's the case. Had thought that it was an obedient droid given it was ready to self-destruct on its programmed orders.

Comment: @Valorum might have a point (at least in Legends) [IG-88's Droid Army](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-88%27s_Droid_Army)

Comment: @Skooba This question is not about IG-88 specifically, though. There were plenty of stable IG-series droids made that functioned as intended --  As assassin droids. The answer probably has to do with cost, with a whole "Seal Team Six vs. Infantrymen" analogy.

Comment: It would be useful to know when IG-88 came online, killing its creators. The timing of this incident may let us know whether or not an army was even possible, as nobody was left to build them.

Comment: @Turbo, sometimes it only takes one. The vast majority of Ford Pintos did not explode into fireballs, and their safety was on par for similar vehicles in the 1970s, and yet mention "Pinto" and that's still the first thing that comes to mind for many.

Comment: Did he just call me a meatbag? Not cool, bro.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They were, and were often used by the Separatists during the Clone Wars.

The jousting droids seen in the 2D *Clone Wars* series are "[IG lancer combat droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG_lancer_combat_droid)", named after the InterGalactic Banking Clan, and a precursor to the IG-88 series:

[image: Screenshot of IG lancer droid]
<sub>(Source: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG_lancer_combat_droid)</sub>

[An equivalent](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG_lancer_droid) also existed in Canon.

Grievous's MagnaGuards were also part of the IG series—here's [IG-101](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-101) and [IG-102](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-102):

[image: Screenshot of Revenge of the Sith, showing Grievous and two MagnaGuards]

There were also some other obscure variants in Legends, including [IG-110 lightsaber droids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-110_lightsaber_droid), and [IG-97 "Imperial battle droids"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/IG-97).

So why weren't the later IG-series droids like IG-11 or IG-88 used for war? They were specifically designed for assassination, so it presumably would have been expensive or otherwise non-ideal to build an army of assassins, for the same reasons it would be if they were organic. Legends and canon continuity also agree (according to [*Tales of the Bounty Hunters*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Bounty_Hunters) and [*The Complete Visual Dictionary, New Edition*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Visual_Dictionary,_New_Edition)) that IG-88 had gone rogue and killed its creators, which wouldn't be ideal for use in warfare.

Comment: Also: The cheapness of regular droids vs the expensive cost of a clone army was one of the few things going in favor of the Separatists. Giving up or reducing this one advantage wouldn't be too smart